# Is it possible to enroll Apple Developer program without ID verification?

Tags: developer-program, verify

I tried to enroll Apple Developer Program with a different name, and I got an email that I should upload an ID to verify my identity. Is it possible to enroll without ID verification?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Are you trying to enroll as an individual or an organization? Can you share screenshot/information from the email that you received?

Comment: Thank you very much. As an individual.

Comment: This is e-mail: 

To proceed with your Apple Developer Program enrollment, we must verify the identity of the developer who will be using the account.

Please upload a copy of the developer’s photo ID. The ID must meet verification requirements for your region:

• Government-issued (example: Passport / Driving License / ID card)
• Valid (not expired)
• Includes the name in Roman characters*
  * If the ID does not include a romanized name, you must also upload a solicitor-certified English translation.

https://developer.apple.com/contact/file-upload/

Comment: Can you please specify which country are you from/trying to enroll into developer account from?

Comment: Turkey, does it depend on country?

Comment: Apple has gone insane. they ask you for ID just to download THEIR SDKs and tools so you can have the privilege of learning how to develop their software.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it seems to be a good idea that Apple is asking for your ID when you're trying to enroll with a different name than your own (I guess this is what you meant by a different name - unless you have two names somehow).

I have never heard of Apple asking for an ID, and then just somehow agreeing to go without ID for no apparent reason. But you could ask Apple to be allowed to enroll without showing an ID - they are afterall the only ones that can determine if you can enroll without it.

If you have problems with the ID, you might consider creating a limited liability company and applying for the developer program with that. However, it is usually not possible to create such a company without identifying yourself.